# StreamReader from MemoryStream UTF8 Encoding

Tags: c#, streamreader, memorystream

I want to open a XML file (from an zip archive) in a MemoryStream and create a StreamReader form this stream to put it into a GridView.

I use this code :

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
entry.Extract(ms);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ms);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(reader);
dataGridView1.DataSource = GlobalDs.Tables[0];
```

If my XML files are encoded in ANSI, it works perfectly.
But when I load files encoded in UTF8, it fail, even I initialize the `StreamReader` like that :

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ms, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

I hope someone will have an idea to solve my problem.

Comment: Your code makes little sense, you are not actually using the reader. DataSet.ReadXml() has a lot of overloads, including one that takes your reader.

Comment: You're not using the `StreamReader` to read the file. Use it in the `ds.ReadXml` call.

Comment: fixed, sorry for my mistake

Answer (score 21):

Try using:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ms, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, true);
```

The third param is for `detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143457.aspx))